# Who should be responsible to protect the Cows from various atrocities?

Tags: scripture, sin, cows

Cow is considered the most sacred animals constituting various deities. They are maintained by cowherds & dairy people.

India is topmost milk producer. But now a days mostly, after when these cows stop giving milk, either they are killed or even worse they are left on the roads on their own to survive. Where they eat garbage, get infected, injured and eventually die in pathetic situation.

Most of us are regular consumers of milk products.
**Questions**:

- Are we responsible for protection of cows from such miserable situation? Or since we paid money for the milk, we are free from the sin?
- What happens to the society as a whole for keeping harmless & helpful animal like cow to die a slow & painful death?